# How to read video directly from the input stream in JavaCV?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I need read live feed from non file source. What I have tried:

```
    FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(in, 1024 * 512);
    grabber.start();

    while (true) {
        Frame frame = grabber.grab();
        canvasFrame.showImage(frame);
    }
```

This snippet works fine files, however it fails to read directly from video feed (it hungs). Is there a way to read video from InputStream without buffering to temporay file using JavaCV

Comment: To get this working without delay, you'll need to set the maximumSize (the second parameter of the constructor for FFmpegFrameGrabber) to 0. If that fails with an error though, it means that the format you are using does not support streaming.